# php - fpdf select case $row

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF and have the following code:

```
// Data
foreach($data as $row)
{ 
$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'','','C'); //Year
$this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'','','R'); //Details
$this->Cell($w[14],6,number_format($row[14],0,",","."),'',0,'R'); //Totals
$this->Ln();
}
```

I would like to have select case and have something like that:

```
for i=1 to 7
  select case $row
    case 1
    case 2
    ..
  end select
loop
```

I would like to have to each row of data different style, and since I know that the rows are repeating every 7 rows, I can have a loop and make selection.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide an example of the desired results and what you have tried so far. It isn't really clear what you are trying to do. If I'm guessing correctly you simply need to have a single variable that you increment each time through the `foreach` and use your `switch` to change the styling depending on the value of that variable.

Comment: @Dave need to count rows(from 1 to 7 then loop) and switch to change style base on row.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make it any clearer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide you the details to move forward. It wasn't clear from what you provided what type of styling you were going to do for each of the 7 row styles so I simply put in a comment for each of the possibilities.

```
$stylecount = 1;
// Data
foreach($data as $row) {
   switch ($stylecount) {

       case 1:
           // set style 1 here
       break;

       case 2:
           // set style 2 here
       break;

       case 3:
           // set style 3 here
       break;

       case 4:
           // set style 4 here
       break;

       case 5:
           // set style 5 here
       break;

       case 6:
           // set style 6 here
       break;

       case 7:
           // set style 7 here
           $stylecount = 0;  // reset count
       break;
   }  // end of switch

   $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
   $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'','','C'); //Year
   $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'','','R'); //Details
   $this->Cell($w[14],6,number_format($row[14],0,",","."),'',0,'R'); //Totals
   $this->Ln();
   $stylecount++;  // bump stype count by 1
}
```